# how to view ArcGis metadata in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, metadata, arcgis

Does anyone know how to view ArcGIS 10 metadata in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 0):

I would just implement a web page or web part in SharePoint that uses the Javascript API.. ESRI have a lot of examples here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm